# What is the meaning of the '^' prefix in TensorFlow GraphDef input names?

Tags: tensorflow, naming-conventions, tensorflow-serving

Some TensorFlow saved models contain a `'^'` in front of an input name. Do these names have a specific meaning? How are they different from regular inputs? For example:

```
node {
  name: "init"
  op: "NoOp"
  input: "^Variable/Assign"
  input: "^Variable_1/Assign"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means **control inputs**, i.e., manually added dependent ops ([more on this here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies)). From the [`NodeDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/node_def.proto#L26) protobuf message documentation:

> Each input is "node:src_output" with "node" being a string name and "src_output" indicating which output tensor to use from "node". If  "src_output" is 0 the ":0" suffix can be omitted.  Regular inputs may optionally be followed by control inputs that have the format **"^node"**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it is probably a mutable tensor.